# Каким образом сделать проложение маршрута

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Здравствуйте.  Каким образом можно сделать простенькое проложение маршрута, что-то на подобии http://www.gocar.by/Trip/RegisterStep1 
может есть готовые решения, примеры?

Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовые сервисы [google directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=ru), [osrm](http://map.project-osrm.org/) ([osrm http api](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md))